# Is there a way to detect which css actually I'm using on my pages and throw everything else?

Tags: css

I have an huge .css file and I was wondering if there was a way to detect which css I'm actually using on my pages so as to eliminate everything else that I do not use. Is there a website? App?

Answer (score 6):

use one of the following

Chromes Audit tab in Developer tools

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/css-usage/

https://unused-css.com/